# Proportionally distribute a lump sum between a maximum and a minimum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I have to distribute a number, x, to a certain number of people, n. I know that I want to distribute the maximum, a, to the top person, and the minimum, b, to the lowest person.

My question is, what is a function given x, n, a, and b, that will evenly distribute n values between a and b between the x people.

For example: if I have 10,000 dollars, I want to give 1000 to the top earner and 200 to the bottom. How much do I give to each person in between so that the remaining 8,800 dollars are distributed proportional to the rank of the person?

Comment: You can't make it proportional to their rank and also give them less, and have a minimum and maximum fixed. If you want a rule that distributes the total in a strictly decreasing order according to ascending rank, there is more information needed. Do you want consecutive differences to be the same or proportional or anything at all; how trivial a solution is acceptable? Can you guarantee that there is great enough $n$ to distribute $x$ within those conditions? Your example is impossible if you have less than 10 people.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by evenly distribute?
In order of ratings, you give y more for each person
b, b + y, b + 2y, b + 3y, ... b + (n - 1)y?
Then x = nb + n(n - 1)y/2 = nb + n(a - b)/2.
So you can find y but x becomes fixed.
The problem is over determined.

So bottom gets b, top gets a and there is x - a - b
left for everybody else who gets (x - a - b)/(n - 2)?